# Hiding text in plain sight

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

EDITED:

I have an accordion similar to this one under. I have several paragraphs of these groups. I just added a nifty search bar to the page which sorts out the text. Pretty much like the one in the example. The thing I have still to figure out is; Is it possible for me to have a code that displays the words: No results, when the last accordion hides? I am really struggeling on this one.

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function mySearch(e) {
        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".panel a").each(function(){
          if($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(text)){
            $(this).parents(".panel").show();
          }else{
            $(this).parents(".panel").hide();
          }
        });
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<body>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Søk..">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Test 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Test 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Test 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>


<br><br><br>
<h1>This be a test</h1>
<br>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Test 4</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Test 5</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Test 6</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want to search on all Accordion Group's title?

Comment: Yes. "Test 1" "Test 2" Etc.. I have over 60 in my original and a lot more to come. So I really need this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you updated your question, I also updated my javascript code. Please remove your javascript and add my code to the end of page.
Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgKgeP

JS code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on('input', function () {
        var search_term = $(this).val();

        if(search_term == '')
        {
            $(".no_result").hide();
            $(".panel-title").parent().parent().show();
            return true;
        }

        search_term = search_term.toUpperCase();

        $('.panel-title').each(function(i, obj) {
            var text = $(this).text().trim();
            if(text.toUpperCase().indexOf(search_term) > -1)
            {
                $(this).parent().parent().show();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            }

            var panel_group = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
            var panel_group_last_element = panel_group.last();

            if(panel_group_last_element.find('h2.no_result').length === 0)
            {
                var html = "<h2 class=\"no_result\" style=\"display:none;\">No results found!</h2>";
                panel_group_last_element.append(html);
            }
            if((panel_group.find('div.panel:visible').length) == 0)
            {
                panel_group_last_element.find('h2.no_result').show();
            } else {
                panel_group_last_element.find('h2.no_result').hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @cosmochen check this out.

Answer (score 2):

`hasResults` is a boolean variable that is set to true only if the search function returns results. Otherwise, a `<div id="noResults"></div>` is populated with the message `<h3>No Results</h3>`:

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function mySearch(e) {
        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var hasResults = false;
        $(".panel a").each(function(){
          if($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(text)){
            $(this).parents(".panel").show();
            hasResults = true;
          }else{
            $(this).parents(".panel").hide();
          }
        });
        
        if(!hasResults){
            $('#noResults').html('<h3>No Results</h3>');
        }
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6%;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<body>

<br><br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Søk..">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div id="noResults"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Test 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Test 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Test 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>


<br><br><br>
<h1>This be a test</h1>
<br>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Test 4</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Test 5</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Test 6</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Check my new comment! :)

Comment: @Cosmochen same concept. Track li elements showing and display a message if there aren't any.

Comment: I don´t use li in that one. Hmmm

Comment: Substitute the li elements for the `.panel` elements

Comment: I can´t get it to work :/ Sorry.. The thing is that I need my script to make the search bar work. And I am not able to configurate it with your changes to where everything works smoothly ..

Comment: I can't get the initial filtering function to work in your new example

Comment: Thats to bad :/ So there is nothing that can be done? Don´t really want to build up everything from scratch just for this little detail you know..

Comment: I think you could fix it without too much effort, but first you need to get the filtering function to work again. When I type text into the search field, the accordion's items don't disappear. If you can't figure that out, maybe post it as a separate question.

Comment: Could you see one more time. Seems to have been a bug with the JS where I had to activate it with enter. It now updates whenever you type and sorts itself like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a little `No Results` message at the bottom of your accordion and toggle it's display depending on whether any results are visible or not, example:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, p, hasResults;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    p = document.getElementById("no-results");
    hasResults = false;
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            hasResults = true;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (hasResults) {
      p.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      p.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  <p id="no-results" style="display: none;">No results</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check my new comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add no results div to your HTML and make it avaiable when no results matched.
Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqVOOy

Add to HTML:

```
<div id="no_results" style="display:none">
<h3>No results</h3>
</div>
```

Update your javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    no_results = document.getElementById("no_results");
    var total_results = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            total_results = total_results + 1;
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    if(total_results == 0)
    {
        no_results.style.display = "";
    } else {
        no_results.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my new comment! :)